# How can I get form fields value by clicking button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here is my html page

```
 <ion-view title="About me">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right"><button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-checkmark-outline" ng-click="updateTextFields(editFormAboutMe, 0, 10000, false)"></button></ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content>
  <form name="editFormAboutMe" class="css-form">
    <div class="list">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <textarea placeholder="Type something about yourself ..." rows="6" name="about" ng-model="editFormAboutMe.editAboutMeFields" ng-maxlength="10"></textarea>
      </label>   
    </div>  
    </form>  
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here is the controller code:

```
$scope.updateTextFields = function(fields, minLen, maxLen, required)
{
    alert(JSON.stringify(fields));
}
```

Here `fields` value is comming `undefined` ? How can I get form fields value inside `updateTextFields` ?

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass the textarea value in updateTextFields method call.

Inside method updateTextFields use **$scope.editAboutMeFields** to get the textarea value. As you are using ng-model it is two way binding and you will get the updated value in method.

Comment: i believe you have injected the correct $scope in your controller. can you also post your controller method that your are calling on ng-click